# Linking between 2 tables laravel

Tags: laravel, relationships

I got two tables: "products" and "productPhotos".
Each product has an unique id = Product_ID.
Each productPhoto has an unique id = ProductPhoto_ID.
In my table productPhoto there is also photo and this is specified like so in my migration: $table->binary('photo'); this is for uploading images.

In the table products I've the ProductPhoto_ID(it's a relationship).
But how must i add 'photo'?

Comment: Do some research on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships . Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the models for each table.

Also is preferable to use laravel conventions for table/column names.

So I would call them like this:

products
 - id
 - etc...

photos
 - id
 - product_id
 - etc...

Then create 2 models:

```
    class Product extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'products';

        public function photos()
        {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Photos');
        }
    }

    class Photo extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'photos';

        public function product()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
        }    
    }
```

Then in your controllers you'll be fine to get relations like this:

$product = Product::find($id)->with('photos');

this will return you a Product model with a property called photos that is a collection of all the Photo models related to it.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Cheers